# window.location in alert must redirect to previous page

Tags: javascript, php

i have the script that will redirect in new page,but i want to that script will redirect in previous page,help me please :(

```
if ($tipe_file != "image/jpeg" AND $tipe_file != "image/pjpeg") {
    echo "<script>window.alert('Upload image failed, file extention must be *.JPG, u can change your file extension in any software like photoshop, coreldraw or other');
    window.location=('../../add.htm')</script>";
}
```

How must i change the script in window.location (blablabla)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `history.back()` to go back to the previous page.

Comment: Can't use `header("Location....` in this case, as the `echo` alert box line appears before the `header` line

Comment: indeed, if one would like to keep the alert the `header` way is not working. Removed it